# Toolbar doesn't appear when not using WindowGroup

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to add a toolbar to my app but it doesn't show up.

```
let root = RootView()
   .toolbar {
         ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                Button("New") {}
         }
    }
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: root)
```

I've tried the same code but with using `WindowGroup` and it does work.
Does it mean that the `toolbar` modifier will only work if my app is using SwiftUI App/Scenes?

Comment: Most probably, and it looks like, yes.